# What is a way to represent non-disjoint union in Coq?

Tags: coq

In Coq, `A+B` is the disjoint sum of types `A` and `B`.

Is there any way to introduce a (possibly) non-disjoint sum of two types?
For example, what if possibly `A` = `B`?

I could not find any information on this online, but perhaps I'm simply thinking about this in the wrong way

Comment: This is a simple question with complicated answers. Do you have a use case in mind, or is this idle curiosity?

Comment: Just a remark: You may have `A = B`.  For instance, the disjoint sum `nat+nat` is a nice data type for the ordinal `omega * 2`.

Comment: The specific use case I am looking at is this: I have two lists of type A and B respectively, where it may be that A = B. I want to compose these lists in some way such that every element in the list is of type A or of type B. Currently I have variable functions for the injections A -> U and B -> U and projections. However, perhaps with the information Pierre provided this might simply be possible with the sum type.

Answer (score 2):

You can't in general. Coq is what's called an intensional type theory; what that means is that every term tells you what type it is, so there's no way to have something that is of two different types. Disjoint union is the best you're going to do. This is one aspect of an important lesson: types aren't sets, and they behave differently in important ways.

Of course, you might have a situation where you can build the union for a specific case. But this will be a special type only applicable to that situation.

Comment: Thank you for this Andrew, I will read more into intensional type theory. And as you said, this is the first time I really notice that types don't behave as sets.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
    Require Import List.
    Import ListNotations. 
    Section AB.
      Variables (A B: Type). 
      Let AB := (A + B)%type.
    
      Definition list_inl (l: list A) : list AB :=
        map (fun a  : A   => inl a) l. 
    
      Definition list_inr (l: list B) : list AB :=
        map (fun b  : B   => inr b) l. 
    
      (* heterogeneous append *)
    
      Definition app' (l: list A)(l' : list B) :=
        list_inl l ++ list_inr l'. 
    
      Fixpoint list_pi1 (l: list AB) : list A :=
       match l with
         | nil => nil
         | inl x::tl  => x:: list_pi1 tl
         | _ :: tl => list_pi1 tl
      end.
    
    End AB.
```

A more technical approach is "heterogeneous lists" by Adam Chlipala
(page 169 of http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/cpdt.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, something like this is what I meant. I will have a look into the book.